# REACT onChange bind this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

So i have this REACT code which should work :

App.jsx:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){             
        super(props);
        this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            questions:[
                {
                    id: 1,
                    text: 'What is your name ?',
                    choices: [
                        {
                            id: 'a',
                            text: 'Michael'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'b',
                            text: 'Brad'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'c',
                            text: 'Steven'
                        }
                    ],
                    correct: 'b'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    text: 'What is your mothers name ?',
                    choices: [
                        {
                            id: 'a',
                            text: 'Sara'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'b',
                            text: 'Sue'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'c',
                            text: 'Donna'
                        }
                    ],
                    correct: 'c'
                },              
                {
                    id: 3,
                    text: 'What is your father name ?',
                    choices: [
                        {
                            id: 'a',
                            text: 'Bobby'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'b',
                            text: 'Harry'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'c',
                            text: 'Wayne'
                        }
                    ],
                    correct: 'a'
                },                              
                {
                    id: 4,
                    text: 'What is your friend name ?',
                    choices: [
                        {
                            id: 'a',
                            text: 'John'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'b',
                            text: 'Paul'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'c',
                            text: 'Dan'
                        }
                    ],
                    correct: 'c'
                }               
            ],
            score: 0,
            current: 1
        }       
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick={this.onChange}>
                <QuestionList {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

QuestionList.jsx :

```
class QuestionList extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="questions">
                {
                    this.props.questions.map(question => {

                        return <Question question={question} key={question.id} {...this.props} />

                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default QuestionList
```

Question.jsx :

```
class Question extends Component {  
    render(){
        const {question} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="well">
                <h3 >{question.text}</h3>
                <hr />
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {
                        this.props.question.choices.map(choice => {
                            return(
                                <li className="list-group-item">
                                    {choice.id} <input type="radio" name={question.id} value={choice.id} /> {choice.text}
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Question
```

except it throws this error in console :  **TypeError: _this.onChange is undefined**

I google it and found out that :

> Make sure you do this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this) in your constructor

But when I add that on my controller i get this error : **TypeError: this.onChange is undefined**

Comment: `this` refers to your `choice` object. Does it have an `onChange` property ?

Comment: Where is the function onChange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Question extends Component {  
    onChange(e) {
       //Your change code here!!
    }
    render(){
        const {question} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="well">
                <h3 >{question.text}</h3>
                <hr />
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {
                        this.props.question.choices.map(choice => {
                            return(
                                <li className="list-group-item">
                                    {choice.id} <input type="radio" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} name={question.id} value={choice.id} /> {choice.text}
                                </li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Question
```

You should have a onChange method in your class.

Comment: Apparentelly its on the Question I must add onChange()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put it in the `constructor` you need to do it like this:

Note: this is an example from the react docs, which are linked below

```
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange() {} // add this 

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onChange}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Comment: I tryed your solution and it throws the same error ... I think I should put here all code just to get the closest answer to the solution.

Comment: Done ... added all files

Comment: can you add your attempt at the code above? I dont see you adding it to the constructor of component...

Comment: Sorry I put the original code ... I'll edit now your fix

Comment: Now i integrated your initial response into the code ... It still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

To avoid an error with binding this, you have two options:

1. Using `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);` (inside constructor)
2. Using arrow function for onClick function

I hope this trick helps you.